# How to load iframe view to specific location on source page based on DOM attributes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I have an iframe referencing another website that is outside of the current domain.  Because there is no way (that I know of) to get the data from the page and sift through it with javascript, I'm trying to simply load the iframe to the part of the page that I want.  I am simply trying to isolate the contents of a paragraph tag  `<p>`, and have the iframe scroll to that point on page load, and disable scrolling. Here is what my code looks like, we'll use yahoo in our example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.yahoo.com" id="testIframe" style="width:400px; height:500px"></iframe>
```

The attribute that I want to get, has a unique class on it, only found once on the page.

```
<body>
  <p>some text...at the top of the iframe by default</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p class="stream-summary">THIS IS THE TEXT THAT I WANT TO BE AT THE TOP OF MY IFRAME</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
```

As a side note, the location of this unique class will vary depending on the query used when the page loads...depending on it, a different piece of data and a different webpage will be used as the main view of the iframe, so I can't use css margins or anything like that to absolutely position the content of the iframe.

Thank you for the help! And let me know if I can help clarify anything.

Comment: Only way you could do it is if it had an ID and you set corresponding id as hash in iframe src. Beyond that what you are asking can't be done..unless you control the code in iframe also

Comment: woah....so, if the source element that I want, `<p class="stream-summary">` has a unique ID, then it might be possible?  I haven't really used a hash before.  What exactly do you mean by setting a corresponding id in the hash of iframe src?  Something like, `<iframe src="https://www.yahoo.com/#theUniqueID???"></iframe>`. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes...but would be without the `/`... `https://www.yahoo.com#theUniqueID`

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks @charlietfl!

Comment: Hey @cherlietfl, one more question...Do you know if there is any way to use a class for this (url#uniqueID)?  The data that I'm using doesn't have IDs, just classes.  Or if there is a way to like...inject an ID that matches the unique class?

Comment: No..can't be done. You can not access inside the iframe due to *"same origin policy"*

Comment: Alright, thanks again